# trouble using external library in Angular 8

Tags: angular

Basically I am trying to use a `profitWell` script in my angular application this is the script

```
<script id="profitwell-js" data-pw-auth="XXX">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[o]=i[o]||function(){(i[o].q=i[o].q||[]).push(arguments)};
        a=s.createElement(g);m=s.getElementsByTagName(g)[0];a.async=1;a.src=r+'?auth='+
        s.getElementById(o+'-js').getAttribute('data-pw-auth');m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m);
        })(window,document,'profitwell','script','https://public.profitwell.com/js/profitwell.js');
        profitwell('start', { 'user_email': 'USER_EMAIL_HERE' });
</script>
```

now I have put this script in the `<head>` of my `index.html` and removed the `profitWell('start')` from it because I need to wait until a user authenticates before I can send in the emailAddress

so my index.html looks like this

```
<head>
<!-- ... -->
   <script id="profitwell-js" data-pw-auth="XXX">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[o]=i[o]||function(){(i[o].q=i[o].q||[]).push(arguments)};
        a=s.createElement(g);m=s.getElementsByTagName(g)[0];a.async=1;a.src=r+'?auth='+
        s.getElementById(o+'-js').getAttribute('data-pw-auth');m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m);
        })(window,document,'profitwell','script','https://public.profitwell.com/js/profitwell.js');
  </script>
</head>
```

now in my authentication component I have done the following

```
// ...

declare var profitWell: any;

// ...

authenticate() {
   // ...
   profitWell('start', {'user_email': this.email});
}
```

now I can see in my network that the profitWell script is being called but when I call the profitWell method I get the following

`profitWell is not defined`

now it is to my understanding when I add `declare var profitWell: any` that well let me use the global `profitWell` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Try to use window.profitwell and declare window as any.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot same issue `window.profitWell` is not a function

Comment: Try w in small. check last line of js file. I checked https://public.profitwell.com/js/profitwell.js this js file there is no declaration of profitWell in the file. That is why you not able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is spell error on your usage. You need to use like `profitwell` and your used `profitWell`. Here profitWell is the issue.

```
declare var profitwell: any;

// ...

authenticate() {
   // ...
   profitwell('start', {'user_email': this.email});
}
```